# Can I hide page indicator in UIPageViewController?

Tags: swift

I make a fullscreen photo's slideshow by using UIPageViewController. Then, I would like to hide page indicator when user tap on picture.

I have tried to used this code but it doesn't immediately hide the indicator on tap.

```
let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
appearance.isHidden = true
```

Can anyone give me an advice?

Answer (score 0):

The page control is only displayed when you implement these two methods:

```
presentationCountForPageViewController:
presentationIndexForPageViewController:
```

try to remove them from your implementation.

Comment: I need to show page indicator once the slideshow is showing. Then user can turn off page indicator by tap on the screen. Thank you anyway.